# How do I get data from Payfast and insert to the database?

Tags: php, mysqli, payment

I have a bit of a problem here on PayFast. I am a newbie and I want to add user data to the database after the user has successfully made a payment. Here is my form with the user data.Your help will be much appreciated!

```
<form name="payment" class="form-inline w3-padding w3-light-grey" method="post" action="https://www.payfast.co.za/eng/process" onsubmit="return validateAmount()">

        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_rec)){ ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="merchant_id" value="12631778"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="merchant_key" value="wcnt1rtsa8g49"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="https://www.capribank.com/das/donations.php"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="https://www.capribank.com/dep/cancel.php"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://www.capribank.com"/>


        <input type="hidden" name="name_first" value="<?php
        echo $row['name'];

        ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="name_last" value="<?php
        echo $row['surname'];

        ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="email_address" value="
        <?php
        echo $row['email'];

        ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="cell_number" value="
        <?php
         echo $row['phone'];
        ?>">

        <input type="hidden" name="m_payment_id" value="<?php
        $digits = 4;
        echo "CPC".str_pad(rand(0, pow(10, $digits)-1), $digits, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="item_description" value="Days - Investment Period"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="custom_int1" value="2"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="custom_str1" value="Extra order information"/>

        <input type="hidden" name="email_confirmation" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="confirmation_address" value="<?php
        echo $row['email'];

        ?>">
        <?php } ?>

        <input type="hidden" name="payment_method" value="eft">

        <div class="form-group">
           Enter amount <input type="text" min="200" class="form-control" name="amount" required="" size="10"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select name="item_name" class="form-control">
            <option value="2 Months - Investment Period">2 Months </option>
            <option value="4 Months - Investment Period">4 Months </option>
            <option value="6 Months - Investment Period">6 Months </option>
            <option value="8 Months - Investment Period">8 Months </option>
            <option value="10 Months - Investment Period">10 Months </option>
            <option value="12 Months - Investment Period">12 Months </option>
           </select> 
        </div>

       <div class="form-group">
           <button name="send" class="w3-btn w3-amber w3-round-large"><strong>Pay Now</strong></button> 
       </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Where is your form?

Comment: Look at the PayFast ITN [sample code](https://developers.payfast.co.za/documentation/#sample-code). It will show you how to retrieve and use the return variables sent by the ITN, but you will need to write your own SQL for the database insert. Note - an ITN is **only sent for successful payments**

Answer (score 1):

This is guide for payFast please follow it , they have mentioned that

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1RZh.png)

all the data is returned to notify_url and not return_url , so  write one function to add transaction details to Database 
you will get the no of variables in return which will help you to determine whether transaction has failed to succeeded

[Transaction details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPGlf.png)

[buyer and merchant details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1IFd.png)

[billing details and payment status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMsOf.png)